# c# datatable comparing with another table using 'LIKE' command

Tags: c#, datatable

I have two datatable that stored on row & row1 respectively.

**row datatable**

abc

ab

a

**row1 datatable**

abcccd

a

Therefore, my code is able to use row to compared with row1 but I only get 'a'. 
What I wanted is that when using row to compare with row1, I would get all result that are related with 'a'. I know theres a 'like' command in sql, but I wanted to do it in datatable if there are any methods possible, thanks

```
if (row["Material"].ToString().Contains(row1["Material"].ToString()))

{
    /// logic
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
//Get the matched data from row
foreach(DataRow r in row1.Rows)
    {
        DataRow[] matchings = row.Select($"Meterial like '%{r["Meterial"]}%'");
        if(matchings.Length>0)
        {
            //logic
        }
    }
```

OR

```
//Get the matched data from row1
foreach(DataRow r in row.Rows)
    {
        DataRow[] matchings = row1.Select($"Meterial like '%{r["Meterial"]}%'");
        if(matchings.Length>0)
        {
            //logic
        }
    }
```

You may change following expression based on your need:

```
'%{r["Meterial"]}%' // Matches where ever it finds text

'{r["Meterial"]}%'  // Matches if starts with

'%{r["Meterial"]}'  // Matches if ends with
```

Comment: erm i get Datarow does not have definition select error

Comment: dude sorry i found the solution for my problem dy for the row.Select im using the for each one instead of datatable

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (row["Material"].Where(x => x.ToString().Contains(row1["Material"].ToString()))) 
{ 
//Code here
}
```

Comment: Bro i get "Object does not contain definition for Where"